# Have R take name of new variable from within a list or a vector

Tags: r, variables, renaming

I have a dataset like this:

```
retailer_id transaction_id  user_id products    total      
D31 700 4   water   1      
D31 701 17  coffee  2      
D31 702 68  coffee  2      
D31 703 78  water   1      
D31 704 4   juice   3
```

where the `retailer_id` column will only ever have one value. I will create multiple vectors, e.g. total cost, average price and whatever else and then I want to join them into a dataframe or vector that takes the name `D31`. I cannot find any process which would pull `D31` and then make a new vector or dataframe with that name.

Since I am automating this as part of a reporting process, I need to have the name of this new dataframe that the value within `retailer_id`.

Comment: Please provide some form of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Why do you think you need to dynamically create variable names? Can't you store the data in a named list or something? It doesn't sound like you are doing things in a very R-like way.

Comment: Your question seems pretty unclear to me, but I suppose you're looking for `assign`. Or at list you think you are looking for it. Probably better than using "variable variable names" is using a list.

Comment: Please look through this [post on making great R examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Your question currently does not contain a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry was struggling to get the image in. My apologies. I will be building it as part of an overall reporting process, so it needs to automatically take this name.

Comment: You need to explain why this was not completely answered by  user2706569's comment.

Comment: I think I don´t understand very well your question but I believe `str_split_fixed()` could help you to do what you want. You could use `" "` for splitting your variable `retailer_id`.